# Merge two files and transpose rows to columns

Tags: awk

Compare first columns from two files. If match, traspose the values for same record from FILE2 to FILE1. If no match is found, fill with "NA"

**FILE1**

```
123 B
124 A
125 N
129 C
134 B
141 T
167 8
179 5
```

**FILE2**

```
123 1 1
123 2 1
124 1 3
124 2 3
129 6 1
129 7 1
134 5 1
134 9 1
167 8 2
167 8 2
```

**Desired Output**

```
123 B 1 2 1
124 A 1 2 3
125 N NA
129 C 6 7 1
134 B 5 9 1
141 T NA
167 8 8 8 2
179 5 NA
```

I have used this code for the missing records but still I cant traspose the rows for found records:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next;}{print $0 "    " ($1 in a ? a[$1] : "NA")}' FILE2 FILE1

123 B    2
124 A    2
125 N    NA
129 C    7
134 B    9
141 T    NA
167 8    8
179 5    NA
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please explain how to get the 3rd column of your expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to collect the list of the file2 2nd column, but only keep the last value of the file2 3rd column.

Here's a bit of perl:

```
perl -lane '
    if ($. == ++$nr) {
        $x{$F[0]} = $F[1];
    } else {
        push @{ $y{$F[0]} }, $F[1];
        $z{$F[0]} = $F[2];
    }
    close ARGV if eof; # reset $. for new file
    END {
        for $key (sort keys %x) {
            printf "%s %s %s\n", $key, $x{$key},
                (exists $y{$key} ? join(" ", @{$y{$key}}, $z{$key}) : "NA");
        }
    }
' file 1 file2
```

```
123 B 1 2 1
124 A 1 2 3
125 N NA
129 C 6 7 1
134 B 5 9 1
141 T NA
167 8 8 8 2
179 5 NA
```

---

as  awk

```
gawk '
    NR == FNR {
        x[$1] = $2
        next
    }
    {
        y[$1] = y[$1] $2 OFS
        z[$1] = $3
    }
    END {
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"
        for (key in x) {
            printf "%s %s %s\n", key, x[key], (key in y ? y[key] z[key] : "NA")
        }
    }
' file{1,2}
```

This uses GNU awk just for the `PROCINFO` variable. If you don't want this dependency, just remove that line and pipe the output into `| sort -k1,1n`

Comment: Hi Glen, Kindly can you do the same using awk.

Comment: I was just in the process of translating when you commented.

Answer (score 1):

based on the current description and input example in the question, this awk code works:

```
 awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2 FS $3 FS $4;next}{print $0,($1 in a?a[$1]:"NA")}' <(awk 'NR%2{printf "%s",$1 FS $2 FS;next}{print $2,$3}' FILE2) FILE1
```

For better reading:

```
 awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2 FS $3 FS $4;next}
      {print $0,($1 in a?a[$1]:"NA")}' 
<(awk 'NR%2{printf "%s",$1 FS $2 FS;next}{print $2,$3}' FILE2)  
FILE1
```

#### with your test data:

```
kent$  head f f2
==> f <==
123 B
124 A
125 N
129 C
134 B
141 T
167 8
179 5

==> f2 <==
123 1 1
123 2 1
124 1 3
124 2 3
129 6 1
129 7 1
134 5 1
134 9 1
167 8 2
167 8 2

kent$  awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2 FS $3 FS $4;next}{print $0,($1 in a?a[$1]:"NA");}' <(awk 'NR%2{printf "%s",$1 FS $2 FS;next}{print $2,$3}' f2) f
123 B 1 2 1
124 A 1 2 3
125 N NA
129 C 6 7 1
134 B 5 9 1
141 T NA
167 8 8 8 2
179 5 NA
```

Comment: Hi Kent, thanks for the code.  Can you explain a little this part of the code.. <(awk 'NR%2{printf "%s",$1 FS $2 FS;next}{print $2,$3}' f2) f

Comment: @OXXO you will see what does it do by executing the awk one liner in the `<(...)`

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  if(++b[$1]==1){
    a[$1]=$2
  }
  else{
    a[$1]=a[$1] OFS $2 OFS $3
  }
  next
}
($1 in a){
  print $1,$2,a[$1]
  next
}
{
  print $0,"NA"
}' Input_file2  Input_file1
```

Output will be as follows.

```
123 B 1 2 1
124 A 1 2 3
125 N NA
129 C 6 7 1
134 B 5 9 1
141 T NA
167 8 8 8 2
179 5 NA
```